# Equivalence relation functor representable?

Tags: category-theory, equivalence-relations, representable-functor

Let $E : \mathbf{Set} \to \mathbf{Set}$ be the contravariant functor taking a set $X$ to the set $E(X)$ of distinct equivalence relations on $X$.  It takes (I assume) a function $f:X \to Y$ to a function $f^*:E(Y) \to E(X)$ sending each equivalence relation on $Y$ to the relation on $X$ defined by $x_1 \sim x_2$ whenever $f(x_1) \sim f(x_2)$.  Is this functor representable?

---

This is an exercise (9.2.3) from the text "An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions" by Bergman.  In the back of the book, he gives an extremely terse hint that seems to imply it *is* representable.

I'm thinking it's not representable. A representing object $R$ should have $\mathrm{Hom}(-,R) \cong E$.  For a finite set $X$, $E(X)$ is finite, so $\mathrm{Hom}(X,R)$ is finite, so $R$ must be a finite set.  But then, for finite sets $X$, $\mathrm{Hom}(X,R)$ has cardinality $|R|^{|X|}$, while $E(X)$ is the number of partitions on $X$.  There's no number $|R|$ making these values coincide, so I conclude $E$ is not representable.  Is there a mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: The reasoning looks fine to me, at first glance.  Similarly, $E$ does not preserve limits/colimits in the expected way, i.e. the canonical morphism $E(X \sqcup Y) \to E(X) \times E(Y)$ is not always an isomorphism.

Comment: In fact, if $F\ \colon\  \textbf{Set}^{\text{op}}\to\textbf{Set}$ is representable, then it’s represented by $F\left(1\right)$ (where $1$ denotes the singleton). So it suffices to show that the “set of equivalence relations” functor is not represented by the set of equivalence relations on the singleton, which is itself the singleton, and which in particular represents the functor constant at the singleton, which the former manifestly isn’t.